# Can i replace multiple bitfield structs as an array in C?

Tags: c, embedded

I am working on a micro-controller with CAN communication which has 32 mailboxes for communication.
In the header file provided by the manufacturer they have the following declaration:

```
struct CANMSGID_BITS {    // bits  description
   Uint16 EXTMSGID_L:16;  // 15:0
   Uint16 EXTMSGID_H:2;   // 17:16
   Uint16 STDMSGID:11;    // 28:18
   Uint16 AAM:1;          // 29
   Uint16 AME:1;          // 30
   Uint16 IDE:1;          // 31
};

/* Allow access to the bit fields or entire register */
union CANMSGID_REG {
   Uint32               all;
   struct CANMSGID_BITS bit;
};

/* eCAN Message Control Register (MSGCTRL) bit definitions */
struct CANMSGCTRL_BITS {  // bits  description
   Uint16 DLC:4;          // 3:0
   Uint16 RTR:1;          // 4
   Uint16 rsvd1:3;        // 7:5   reserved
   Uint16 TPL:5;          // 12:8
   Uint16 rsvd2:3;        // 15:13 reserved
   Uint16 rsvd3:16;       // 31:16 reserved
};

/* Allow access to the bit fields or entire register */
union CANMSGCTRL_REG {
   Uint32                  all;
   struct CANMSGCTRL_BITS  bit;
};

/* eCAN Message Data Register low (MDR_L) word definitions */
struct CANMDL_WORDS {    // bits  description
   Uint16 LOW_WORD:16;   // 15:0
   Uint16 HI_WORD:16;    // 31:16
};

/* eCAN Message Data Register low (MDR_L) byte definitions */
struct CANMDL_BYTES {  // bits   description
   Uint16 BYTE3:8;     // 7:0
   Uint16 BYTE2:8;     // 15:8
   Uint16 BYTE1:8;     // 23:16
   Uint16 BYTE0:8;     // 31:24
};

/* Allow access to the bit fields or entire register */
union CANMDL_REG {
   Uint32              all;
   struct CANMDL_WORDS word;
   struct CANMDL_BYTES byte;
};

/* eCAN Message Data Register high  (MDR_H) word definitions */
struct CANMDH_WORDS {     // bits  description
   Uint16 LOW_WORD:16;    // 15:0
   Uint16 HI_WORD:16;     // 31:16
};

/* eCAN Message Data Register low (MDR_H) byte definitions */
struct CANMDH_BYTES {  // bits   description
   Uint16 BYTE7:8;     // 7:0
   Uint16 BYTE6:8;     // 15:8
   Uint16 BYTE5:8;     // 23:16
   Uint16 BYTE4:8;     // 31:24
};

/* Allow access to the bit fields or entire register */
union CANMDH_REG {
   Uint32              all;
   struct CANMDH_WORDS word;
   struct CANMDH_BYTES byte;
};

struct MBOX {
   union CANMSGID_REG   MSGID;
   union CANMSGCTRL_REG MSGCTRL;
   union CANMDL_REG     MDL;
   union CANMDH_REG     MDH;
};
```

This is for a single Mailbox but there are 32 mailboxes so the definition for the mailboxes is given as follows:

```
struct ECAN_MBOXES {
   struct MBOX MBOX0;
   struct MBOX MBOX1;
   struct MBOX MBOX2;
   .
   .
   .
   struct MBOX MBOX30;
   struct MBOX MBOX31;
};
```

Finally we have:

```
extern volatile struct ECAN_MBOXES ECanaMboxes;
```

where 'ECanaMboxes' defined in a linker command file.

I have only replaced `struct ECAN_MBOXES` with the following declaration:

```
struct ECAN_MBOXES {
    struct MBOX MBOX[32];
};
```

Is this a valid change or are we not allowed to make arrays out of bitfield?
I have tried the code both ways and the code runs fine either way. I prefer the array because it is easier to access specific mailboxes for a specific purpose and also the configuration of all mailboxes can be done in an iterative manner. I want to know whether the struct declaration will cause any unexpected issues?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Whether `struct ECAN_MBOXES` contains 32 distinct instances of `struct MBOX` or an array of 32 `struct MBOX` has no bearing on how `struct MBOX` is internally laid out.

The latter is obviously preferable since you can index the array but it won't break anything with `struct MBOX`, whether it contains unions and bitfields or not.

Note that you're not actually creating an array of bitfields but an array of structs that contains bitfields.  An actual array of bitfields is not a legal construct, and your compiler would give you an error if you attempted to do so.

Comment: The last point you made is the reason I was confused. I read that an array of bitfield is illegal and should be avoided but I was confused whether a making an array of the structs will also be illegal or it should be fine.

Comment: @ShadabShaikh Glad I could help.  Feel free to [accept this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) if you found it useful.

Answer (score 2):

The change should be fine, bit-fields are not a special case when it comes to arrays.

Note that you need to keep the actual variable declaration of that struct `volatile` as in the original code.

As for `ECAN_MBOXES`, consider using a union instead:

```
typedef union {
   struct                 // C11 anonymous struct
   {
     struct MBOX MBOX0;
     struct MBOX MBOX1;
     ...
   };
   struct MBOX MBOX[32];
}ECAN_MBOXES ;
```

Now if you have `ECAN_MBOXES foo`, you can access it either as `foo.MBOX0` or `foo.MBOX[0]` and it refers to the same mailbox register.

Comment: I kept the variable declaration as volatile didn't change that. But good tip on using using union to use both type of declarations it never occurred to me that I can use both of them if both worked for me.